# Having trouble combining two select statements

Tags: sql

I would like to join these two queries so the data is presented together but I do not know how to join two select statements correctly.

Here is how I attempted it:

```
Select *
FROM    Products.Products
Join
SELECT Products.Prices.ProductID, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='ONEK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS ONEK, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='FIVEK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS FIVEK, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='TENK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS TENK, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='TWENTYFIVEK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS  TWENTYFIVEK,
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='Fifty',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS Fifty, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='OneHundred',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS OneHundred, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='FiveHundred',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS FiveHundred
FROM Products.Prices
GROUP BY Products.Prices.ProductID;
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't really used SQL, you are trying to JOIN without a condition to join on...

Answer (score 0):

Make one query a subquery and define the joining columns:

```
Select *
FROM    Products.Products
Join
(SELECT Products.Prices.ProductID, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='ONEK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS ONEK, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='FIVEK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS FIVEK, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='TENK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS TENK, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='TWENTYFIVEK',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS  TWENTYFIVEK,
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='Fifty',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS Fifty, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='OneHundred',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS OneHundred, 
    Max(IIf(Products.Prices.Code='FiveHundred',Products.Prices.Price,Null)) AS FiveHundred
FROM Products.Prices
GROUP BY Products.Prices.ProductID
) A
ON Products.ProductID = A.ProductID;
```